# Loading last 3 days incremental data from oracle to hdfs using sqoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, hadoop-streaming, sqoop2

How to import last 3 days incremental data from oracle to hdfs using Sqoop.

Currently i have written generic sqoop command using  Shell-Script to import data from multiple oracle database for multiple plants.

So can anyone help me how to write sqoop command to import the last 3 days data.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far? This site is very good at helping you improve what you have done and not very good at doing it all for you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, StackOverflow is neither a forum, tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can help with [certain problems](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's your job to [put some efforts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) in the first place, including elementary [(re)search](https://www.google.com). Read [stack overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Did you tried out sqoop job in oozie ? you can schedule them accordingly.

help - http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.0/DG_SqoopActionExtension.html

Comment: Please provide what you have done so far? based on how you designed your sqoop job we can provide you with the options. Also remove the hadoop streaming tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your SQOOP job you can issue SQL so in your SQL statement you can add a date function to the Where clause assuming the table you are pulling from has a date column.

Example: select ,,... from  where  >= (CURRENT-DATE -3);